# Windows: Handle segfaults in all threads

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, signals, segmentation-fault

I'm looking for a way to catch segfaults and other errors anywhere in a program (which uses multiple threads, some of which are created by external libraries). I'm using Visual Studio 2013 with the Intel C++ Compiler 2015.

Some external DLL's - in some cases I've even seen this with Windows drivers - can contain bugs that are out of my control, and my software runs 24/7 - I need to be able to log a crash somewhere and restart my software.

So far, I found that you can set a signal handler which handles SIGSEGV and other signals. Based on what I read, under Linux this would do exactly what I need (handle this signal for all threads), but under Windows you need to set the signal handler for each thread separately. Since I'm not the one who creates all the threads (if I was, I could just use __try/__catch), this isn't really an option. On top of that, I'm seeing that when I set a signal handler in a thread and then cause a SIGSEGV it doesn't get handled by the handler, while the exact same code works fine in the main thread - not sure what's going on there (but even a fix for that wouldn't help, since I don't create all the threads, and looping through all existing threads in my process to set handlers sounds like a very bad idea).

So, is there a way to do this? Googling and searching here did not help - I found several people with similar questions but no answers that are usable in my situation.

Note: What I have now, which works perfectly in the main thread but not at all if I copy this same block of code to any thread:

```
SignalHandlerPointer previousHandlerSEGV = signal(SIGSEGV, SignalHandler);
int *a;
a = NULL;
*a = 0;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get notified about all unhandled exceptions in a process you can call [SetUnhandledExceptionFilter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680634.aspx). The functionality is documented as:

> Issuing SetUnhandledExceptionFilter replaces the existing top-level exception filter for all existing and all future threads in the calling process.

Inside the exception filter it is recommended to trigger a call to [MiniDumpWriteDump](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680360.aspx) (in an external process), to produce a mini dump for off-line analysis. You get to control the amount of information that is written into the mini dump (e.g. threads, modules, call stacks, memory). Most importantly, you can dump the call stack of the thread that raised the uncaught exception, **at the time the exception is raised**.

As an alternative, I believe some/most/all of this can be done automatically by registering for [application recovery and restart](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc948909.aspx).

Comment: SetUnhandledExceptionFilter doens't work because this isn't an exception. But, it looks like your link about registering for application recovery and restart works fine! I did have to tweak it a bit to keep it compatible with Windows XP (I still have many people using my software on XP... It's a 24/7 thing that doesn't require internet access). Anyway, with LoadLibrary inside an if I managed to get it to work!

Comment: @HansvanZutphen: What you consider to be a "seg fault" is in fact implemented as an [SEH exception](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680657.aspx) in Windows. Setting the unhandled exception filter does **exactly** what you had in mind.

Comment: Hm... it didn't work when I tried it. Also try/catch doesn't catch it, you need to use __try and __catch. But I guess it would if I would choose the (non-standard) compiler flag "/EHa (Yes with SEH exceptions)".

Comment: @HansvanZutphen: SEH is a system service, that's unrelated to any compiler settings. `int* a = nullptr; *a = 42;` will always trigger an access violation SEH exception (error code `0xC0000005`), that can be filtered using the [`__except` keyword](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s58ftw19.aspx), or in an unhandled exception filter (as set up using `SetUnhandledExceptionFilter`).

Comment: That said, you should always compile your C++ code using the `/EHs` or `/EHsc` compiler switches for portability. Using `/EHa` would cause a C++ `catch(...)` clause to intercept SEH exceptions (like access violations), which should pass through to the unhandled exception filter.

Comment: You're right! I guess I tested it in the debugger before and then it never gets there. But outside of the debugger it does.

Comment: That said, if you ( @HansvanZutphen ) build with no any `/EH` switch at all or with `/kernel` switch, C++ keywords try, throw and catch will all of a sudden become unavailable. But mutch to your surpise the full MS STL will work, minus C++ exceptions. Ask yourself:  what is the '/kernel' switch for?

Comment: @che The [/kernel](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/kernel-create-kernel-mode-binary) option caters to the particularities of code that runs in kennel more. Allocating freestore memory is not generally allowed, and the `/kernel` option disables C++ features that would implicitly attempt to do so. This is not specific to C++ exceptions, although they do fall into this category. With that I feel that I'm missing the point you were trying to make.

Comment: The "point I am trying to make" is: there is this ['/kernel` switch](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/kernel-create-kernel-mode-binary?view=vs-2019). Read the ms docs page and use it as prescribed. That gives you dear OP what you Mr IInsepctable has answered, and much more.  "Allocating freestore memory is not generally allowed, and the /kernel option disables C++ features that would implicitly attempt to do so" ... that is interesting ... can you Mr IInsepcatable point us to some source where we can learn about this issue?

Comment: @che How does disabling C++ exceptions by way of the `/kernel` option help the OP to *"to catch segfaults and other errors"*? And how would you propose to enable the `/kernel` option retroactively for 3rd-party binaries?

Comment: @IInspectable you are still chasing me around SO, I am honoured (laugh) ... for my own and other peoples benefits, I am using this [simple repo](https://github.com/DBJDBJ/kernel_ms_stl) with a very long readme, while on the journey of discovery about this exact kind of issues. It is a journey of discovery because as more I go into this, the more I am confused with [MS DOCS pages on the subject](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/eh-exception-handling-model?view=vs-2019). If you are able and willing to help please do so over there.